# Analyzing the impact of a binary variable on ordinal response by various levels of a continuous variable using the mgcv package for gam model

Tags: r, interaction, ordinal-data, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

There is a dataset consisting of 1100 in vitro fertilization cycles from 800 patients, indicating that some patients have undergone more than two cycles. The dataset contains 1100 rows. Each cycle begins with the measurement of a “hormone” level. Additionally, there is an "ethnicity" variable with three categories: Caucasian, Hispanic, and Afro-American. Furthermore, a binary variable called "drug" indicates whether the drug was prescribed or not after measuring the hormone levels. The outcome variable is a ratio representing the success of each cycle. The success variable has been coded as an ordinal variable with 5 levels, ordered in terms of increasing success.

I aim to address the following two questions through modeling:

1. How does the success level vary across different hormone levels, considering whether the drug was prescribed or not, and for different ethnicities?
2. Does the prescription of the drug significantly increase the success rate? If so, at which hormone levels and for which ethnicities does it have a significant effect? In other words, at which hormone levels should I consider prescribing the drug?

To address these questions, I used a Generalized Additive Model (GAM) from the mgcv package:

```
mgcv::gam(Success_5 ~ s(Hormone, by = interaction(Drug, Ethnicity)) +
                      s(Patient, bs = "re"),
          data = dataframe,
          method = "REML", family = ocat(R = 5), select = FALSE)
```

Regarding the visualization, I want to understand the effect of drug prescription on different ethnic groups and at different levels of the continuous hormone variable. Should I expect different success levels when the drug is prescribed versus when it is not? Or would the plot primarily show similar mean success rates across different hormone levels, with slight variations in the hormone smoothes?

Or should I modify the model as follows to visualize the effect correctly?

```
mgcv::gam(Success_5 ~ s(Hormone, by = interaction(Drug, Ethnicity)) +
                      s(Hormone) +
                      Drug +
                      Ethnicity +
                      s(Patient, bs = "re"),
          data = dataframe,
          method = "REML", family = ocat(R = 5), select = FALSE)
```

What is the correct way to construct the model? How can I accurately visualize and report the effect of drug prescription on different ethnic groups and at various levels of the continuous hormone variable? Lastly, how can i present a cutoff for hormone levels for prescribing drug?

Comment: Both your models are wrong; you need whatever factor you pass to `by` to be also included as a parametric factor effect (in your case an interaction so you need to add `Drug * Ethnicity` to the first call and `Drug:Ethnicity` to the second model. You need these parametric factor effect to model the group means as each group's smooth is centred about 0 (the intercept) and hence doesn't include the group mean.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thank you very much. So is it true that model should be as; `Success_5 ~ s(Hormone, by = interaction(Drug, Ethnicity)) + s(Hormone) + Drug + Ethnicity + Drug*Ethnicity`? I think I should add also s(Hormone) term to the first model right? Therefore i will have estimates and p values for the terms below (I assume as Drug0 and Ethnicity1 are the reference); _Ethnicity2, Ethnicity3, Drug1, Drug1 * Ethnicity2, Drug1 * Ethnicity3, 6 interaction terms of s(Hormone) * Drug(2levels) * Ethnicity(3levels), s(Hormone)_

Comment: Additionally, could you provide advice on how to interpret the estimates for the ordinal response, at least for factor variables? I'm wondering if it's possible to create a plot with hormone levels on the x-axis and the linear predictor on the y-axis, with different curves for each 6 groups. Can this be achieved by deriving the responses of the linear predictor using the predict function?

Comment: Furthermore, when creating these plots, should the limits of each ordinal level align with the values of the "Ordered Categorical (-1, 0.07, 5.15)" of the linear predictor as in your [previous explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226645/generalized-additive-model-interpretation-with-ordered-categorical-family-in-r)

Because in this example the the limits of ordinal variables in the figure you presented do not pass from the -1, 0.07 and 5.15 points.

Comment: ` Success_5 ~ s(Hormone, by = interaction(Drug, Ethnicity)) + s(Hormone) + Drug + Ethnicity + Drug*Ethnicity ` For this model should i also include _s(Hormone, by = Drug)_ and _s(Hormone, by = Ethnicity)_ terms?

Comment: Could you organise your questions in these comments into a coherent edit to your original question? If you can't provide a reproducible example, I may not answer specifics about interpretation that aren't already covered in other answers.